# Questions to speaker for smartphone / University purpose

Tags: gratis, android, ios, video-conferencing

I was at the MIT-Vienna-Conference and they had a pretty nice App-System (Superevent), where Questions to the Speaker could be asked per the Superevent-app, upvoted from others and finally answered by the speaker, all without handraising etc.

I now would like to try to implement that sort of "Guerilla" in my University for Lectures, since the Professors will never agree to use sth like this in the near future. Therefore i also don´t have the money to buy a Conference App. Most of them are restricted to 25-75 people in the free plan, but we normally have 150-200 people sitting in a lecture.

So here´s my question: Does anybody know of free solutions of this?

My primal need is: Question to speaker-App for Android and iOS

My wish would be: An own "Help-area" for each lecture, possibility to provide resource-links, up and downvote(Evaluation) of lecture.

I could get my hand around some money by asking the student commitee, but most of the conference apps work on a plan per conference, which would be way to expensive for all the lectures in my study.

Thanks a lot!